# Prove that $ES \leq \sigma$, with S being a random sample

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, sampling

Assume we have a random sample S of (X1,...,Xn) from a population with finite variance $\sigma^2$.  Prove that $ES \leq \sigma$

How would you prove this?  Is there some way to do this using Jensen's inequality?  If not, what other faster way is there?

Comment: What is the definition of $S$?

Comment: S would be the square root of the variance.

Comment: Is $S = \sqrt{\dfrac{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar{X})^2}{n-1}}$ with $E[S^2]=\sigma^2$?  Or is $S = \sqrt{\dfrac{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar{X})^2}{n}}$ with $E[S^2]=\dfrac{n-1}{n}\sigma^2$?

Comment: S would be the standard deviation so the one I was thinking of was the first one.  Does that not work?

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(y) = y^{1/2}$. Since this is a concave function, we can apply Jensen's inequality if we flip the direction of the relationship: $E(g(y)) \leq g(E(y))$.
Setting $y = s^2$ the result $E(s) \leq \sigma$ follows naturally.